# How do you get the instance id from a TextInput in the on_text function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy

I am trying to make a sudoku game in Kivy 1.10.1.  I have a screen with 81 TextInputs that simulate the board in a screen like this

```
<NewGame>
    GridLayout:
        cols: 9
        rows: 9
        TextInput:
            id: "row_0_col_0"
            on_text: root.set_value(self)
        TextInput:
            id: "row_0_col_1"
            on_text: root.set_value(self)
        ....
        TextInput:
            id: "row_8_col_8"
            on_text: root.set_value(self)
```

My gamy.py is

```
class NewGame(Screen):
    new_board = Board(board_data=None)


    def set_value(self, instance):
        Logger.info(f"Self.id is {self.id}")
        Logger.info(f"Instance.id is {instance.id}")
```

However these print `Self.id is None` `Instance.id is None`.  Ultimately I want to store some data in the text input labels, mainly what row/col they represent as I need that to interact with the Board class I created.  How can I get the id?  Or, perhaps add a custom property representing the row and column number of each label to be used in my on_text callback function?

Comment: I thought putting `id: "row_0_col_1"` in my kv file and then passing self into `root,set_value(self)` was how I should be able to pass the values.  I don't have anything else defined.

Comment: You cannot just access `id` in this case it is no class attribute, or at least not the attribute you set in the .kv file. The ids are collected in a dictionary that is assigned to `ids`, you can access it by `self.ids`. If you want to find a certain id, you'll have to write your conditions for that. Same applies to the instances id. To bypass this you could add a `custom_value: 'your value'` to `TextInput` which then is accessible in your python code by `instance.custom_value`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add `row` and `col` attributes to the `TextInputs` like this:

```
<NewGame>
    GridLayout:
        cols: 9
        rows: 9
        TextInput:
            id: row_0_col_0
            row: 0
            col: 0
            on_text: root.set_value(self)
        TextInput:
            id: row_0_col_1
            row: 0
            col: 1
            on_text: root.set_value(self)
        TextInput:
            id: row_8_col_8
            row: 8
            col: 8
            on_text: root.set_value(self)
```

Then the `set_value()` method can be:

```
def set_value(self, instance):
    id = "row_" + str(instance.row) + "_col_" + str(instance.col)
    print('id =', id)
```

Note that the `id` values are typically not surrounded by `""`.